# Xamarin RendererFactory.GetRenderer() not working

Tags: xamarin, renderer, xamarin.forms

I am developing a cross-platform control using Xamarin.  My goal is to have a list of selectable items.  I have some iOS code that works fine:

```
    private UIView CreateViewWithTemplate(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row)
            {
                // create our content presenter
                DYMOContentPresenter presenter = new DYMOContentPresenter();

                // set its data template to the one from our control
                presenter.ItemTemplate = this._pickerControl.ItemTemplate;

                // set the data to the correct item from the list
                presenter.ObjectContent = this._pickerControl.Items.ElementAt((int)row);

                // and use the xamarin forms renderer factory to get a renderer for the item
                IVisualElementRenderer renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(presenter);

                // tell the renderer the size of the view and 
                renderer.SetElementSize(new Size(pickerView.Frame.Width, ROW_HEIGHT));

                // then get the native view and return


 return renderer.NativeView;
        }
```

However, my attempt to implement this in Android is not working:

```
private View CreateViewWithTemplate(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{            
    // create content presenter
    DYMOContentPresenter presenter = new DYMOContentPresenter();

    // set its data template to the correct item from the list
    presenter.ItemTemplate = this._pickerControl.ItemTemplate;

    // set data to correct list item
    presenter.ObjectContent = this._pickerControl.Items.ElementAt((int) position);

    // use Xamarin forms renderer factory to get a renderer for the item
    IVisualElementRenderer renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(presenter);

    presenter.Layout(new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, parent.Width, ROW_HEIGHT));
    renderer.UpdateLayout();
    renderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();
    renderer.ViewGroup.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(parent.Width, ROW_HEIGHT);
    renderer.ViewGroup.Layout(0, 0, parent.Width, ROW_HEIGHT);
    renderer.ViewGroup.BuildDrawingCache();

    // get native view and return
    return renderer.ViewGroup;
}
```

I can see individual list view rows but no text appears within them.  I can see text after commenting out this code and replacing it with a simple `TextView`, so I suspect there is something wrong with the renderer.  I have tried many variants of this code as well (specifying `LayoutParams`, attempting to resize the child, etc.).  Nothing seems to work.